# Rails error with git push heroku master error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sqlite

I'm trying to push my git on heroku. For this i use :

```
$ git push heroku master
```

return :

```html
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_ae596310505cf83afbb45a2986208c96/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_ae596310505cf83afbb45a2986208c96/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to glacial-taiga-8832.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/glacial-taiga-8832.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/glacial-taiga-8832.git'
```

If i do :

```
$ sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'
```

it works but same problem.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `sqlite3` gem into the `development` section of your Gemfile. Heroku doesn't have the SQLite database installed.

Example:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

To use the database on Heroku you need to use PostgreSQL database (by default). To make it work you need to add the `pg` gem into the `production` group:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Also, there are some chances that you will need to update your `database.yml`, but I believe Heroku will just inject their database connection setting in your config file.