# Unable to push git repo from cloud9 to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

New to ROR, Heroku. Trying to deploy  a simple ROR app into Heroku.
Using Cloud9 IDE and repo is on bitbucket.org.

Specifically Im getting the error pertaining to SQLite3, I made the changes to my GEMFILE as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682681/rails-error-with-git-push-heroku-master-error/33682835#33682835)

But still facing the same problem, checked in Heroku forum, here in [one post](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-install-gems-via-bundler/239) they are advising to upgrade the 'bundler' on Heroku, how to do this?

Simply clueless how to resolve this problem.

Kindly help us out. Thanks in advance.

Error code is listed below

```
prompt$:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 17.40 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.3
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.2
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.1
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.2
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.2
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.99
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.2
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.2
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.20
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.3
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.2
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.1
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.2
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.2
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.99
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.2
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.2
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.20
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_b45bff3ea06b94009d0ea978218e72b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to mighty-citadel-7706.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mighty-citadel-7706.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mighty-citadel-7706.git'
```

Comment: Can you show your gemfile?

Comment: Recently I did the same thing with a project on heroku, attempting to use SQLLite for development and Postgres on heroku for production.  I do not recommend it.  Even after making the change recommended in the post, I got the same error, I cannot explain why heroku wants to install development gems.  Their documentation, however, [Getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app), recommends removing the sqllite reference and installing postgres for development.